# Passing two values for one parameter inside RemoteFunction

Tags: ajax, grails, parameters

**GSP**

```
<g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'CSE','DISPLAYADS','EMAIL','MOBILEWEB','OTHERS','ORGANIC','SEO', 'SEM']" name="mv" id = "mv" 
           onchange="${remoteFunction(
           controller:'Pgtyp', 
           action:'ajaxGetMv', 
           params:'\'mv=\' + escape(this.value)+\'&date_hour=\'+z+\'&date_hour=\'+ b',
           //params:'\'mv=\'+this.value',
           onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}"
></g:select>
```

**Controller**

```
def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.date_hour ,p.visits, p.mv, p.browser,p.pagetype,p.platform,p.device,p.time_period from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ? and p.date_hour >= ? and p.date_hour <= ?  order by col_0_0_ asc ",[params.mv, params.date_hour,params.date_hour])
```

This is what I tried for passing two values for one parameter. What am I doing wrong? How do i make it work?

**UPDATE1**

This is the error that I got:

```
ERROR:Expected positional parameter count: 3, actual parameters: [SEO, [[Ljava.lang.String;@6e5980, [Ljava.lang.String;@6e5980]] [select p.date_hour ,p.visits, p.mv, p.browser,p.pagetype,p.platform,p.device,p.time_period from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ? and p.date_hour >= ? and p.date_hour <= ? order by col_0_0_ asc ]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Expected positional parameter count: 3, actual parameters: [SEO, [[Ljava.lang.String;@6e5980, [Ljava.lang.String;@6e5980]] [select p.date_hour ,p.visits, p.mv, p.browser,p.pagetype,p.platform,p.device,p.time_period from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ? and p.date_hour >= ? and p.date_hour <= ? order by col_0_0_ asc ]
    Line | Method
->>   13 | doCall    in marchmock2.PgtypController$_closure1$$EOkBYvqz
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `params.list()` method in your controller:

```
def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.date_hour ,p.visits, p.mv, p.browser,p.pagetype,p.platform,p.device,p.time_period from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ? and p.date_hour >= ? and p.date_hour <= ?  order by col_0_0_ asc ", [ params.mv ] + params.list( 'date_hour' ).collect{ dateFormatter.parse( it ) } )
```

Comment: ah sorry, I took the other param name

Comment: see the update. `dateFormatter` comes from the previous question. btw, in your DB the `date_hour` is of date_time type, right?